# graphing milliseconds in python matplotlib.dates

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have time tagged data formatted using datetime.datetime.strptime that includes milliseconds.  The data can span from a few minutes to a few hours.  When I plot using pyplot and zoom in, it seems the minimum tick mark is 1 second.  It appears that matplotlib's TickHelper RRuleLocator only has a SecondLocator.  Is there a way to include millisecond resolution when zoomed in?

```
receivedTime = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(data[1]), "%H:%M:%S.%f")

fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,.8,.8])
fig.autofmt_xdate()

ax.plot(times, prices, color='blue', lw=1, drawstyle='steps-post', label = prices)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Matplotlib uses Matlab like numbers (seconds since 1970) for dates. If you have milliseconds, you must convert the dates to 'number':

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
ntimes = mdates.num2epoch(times / 1000.0)
```

and plot `ntimes` instead of `times`.